# Concatenating Header with Buffer Contents

Tags: c

I'm reading a file block by block and sending that over a TCP connection. With each block I have to prepend a short header before I send the message. For the life of me, I cannot get this to work:

```
do {
    bytes_read = fread( &buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE-sizeof("your_file||")-1, fp );
    bzero(message, BUFFSIZE);
    strcpy(message, "your_file|");

    for (j=0; j<bytes_read; ++j) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", buffer[j]);
        message[j+9] = buffer[j];
    }

    strcat(message, "|");
    strcat(message, "\0");
    fprintf(stdout, "message:    %s\n\n", message);
} while (!feof(fp1));
```

My printf output shows the perfect data, so I know that I am reading correctly. But I cannot get this message. This is what my output looks like:

```
BEGIN_LINE000This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE000
message:    your_file|

BEGIN_LINE001This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE001
BEGIN_LINE002This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE002
BEGIN_LINE003This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE003
BEGIN_LINE004This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE004
BEGIN_LINE005This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE005
BEGIN_LINE006This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE006
BEGIN_LINE007This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE007
BEGIN_LINE008This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE008
BEGIN_LINE009This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LImessage:    your_file|

NE009
BEGIN_LINE010This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE010message:    your_fileNE009
BEGIN_LINE010This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE010|
```

I'm sure that I am overlooking something really simple, but I've spent hours trying different methods to solve this and I always come back to the same problem. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the `for` loop ends up leaving a properly-terminated string in `message`, unless you know that the last character of `buffer` is always going to be `'\0'`.

This failure to terminate makes it dangerous to call `strcat()` on `message`, and also (of course) to print it as a string.

Comment: I'm sure that it isn't properly terminated. How do I put the nul terminator at the end of it? I've tried `message[j] = '\0'` but that just gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: should have said `message[j+9] = '\0'`